RANKX Issue when replacing a measure by its own expression
I have a sales table with columns OrderQty and Product Key
I've created a measure TotalQty=SUM(Sales[OrderQty])
I want to get the Rank of each product regarding its own TotalQty value against TotalQty values of all other product
The measure Rank=RANKX(ALL(Products),TotalQty) works fine and I get the following outcome:

Now I replace TotalQty by its expression in the measure Rank:
Rank=RANKX(ALL(Products),SUM(Sales[OrderQty]))
And I get the number 1 for each line of the matrix:

This seems strange to me, since, in my understanding, TotalQty is equal to SUM(Sales[OrderQty]) and as a result should behave the same way. Do you have an explanation?
Thanks in advance.

Re-write your second formula like this:
Rank=RANKX(ALL(Products),CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[OrderQty])))

It now should give the same results as the first formula.
The reason is - when you are using a measure, it's always automatically wrapped into CALCULATE function. So, your first formula is not really SUM(Sales), it's CALCULATE(SUM(Sales)). This is called "syntax sugar", a concept DAX uses to make code cleaner and easier to read.
CALCULATE function makes a critical difference inside iteration functions like RANKX, SUMX, etc. For each iteration, it converts current row into a filter context, a process called "context transition".
